# Angular 2 router navigates undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

Every time I click on a link and a new component is loaded, the following error is thrown.

[image]

The line that zone shows like responsive-height.component.ts:111 is wrong, there's no http connections in there.

In previous versions of angular, this only happens with built files, not in development environment, but up to 2.2, it happens in dev mode as well.

I don't know if the problem is related to angular2-router or angular-cli.

Currently I use angular 2.3.1 with angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**
My routes are there, I delete several in the middle that are the same, and change some domain names by foo bar.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component1,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'foo/bar',
    component: Component2
  },
  {
    path: 'user/profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule {
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The aplicación works properly, no weird behaviors. But this error is thrown and I want to fix it.

**UPDATE 3:**

The app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ErrorModule,
    HeaderModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    RoutingModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language
    },
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions},
    {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend},
    {provide: Http, useExisting: HttpInterceptor},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: @MKK `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are gone 6+ months ago ;-)

Comment: RouterModule than  @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @MMK it's https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer happy :)

Comment: Please provide the `AppRoutingModule` usually in `app-routing.module.ts` at the `app` directory, and your `app.module.ts` file

Comment: You can delete the `providers`, and did you import `RoutingModule` in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @Nir Please, you don't need to specify me where. I'm not newbie. Yes I import it in the routing module.

Comment: @Serginho just trying to help.. I'm guessing that you import `NgModule`, `RouterModule` and `Routes` in this file right? (just making sure)

Comment: Do you still get the error if you use `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, useHash: true)],`? (url in browser url bar looks different this way - just for debugging purposes)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, same error

Comment: Hi @Serginho. Quite newbie, but could you provide your Component1 and NotFoundComponent  (structure at least).

Comment: @GileadKenzo NotFoundComponent only has an image static inside. The project is too big to paste here. So thanks for trying help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, `background-image: none` in a css file causes that error.

Answer (score 0):

For empty path routes without `children` or `redirect`, you need `pathMatch: 'full'`:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component1,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

otherwise the router keeps looking for child routes.

Comment: Ok, but not solves the problem. I changed on top, is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

Missing declarations for components or wrong path in imports

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component1,
    Component2
    ...    
  ]
```

Check your paths. Provide [plunker with your code](http://plnkr.co/)

app.routes.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'shared',
    component: SharedComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule {
}
```

shared.module.ts similiar to header.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule    
  ],
  declarations: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Routes without errors.

Comment: All components are declared in the imported modules. And there's no lazy routes. So that's not the problem

Comment: All components are declared, where can we see it? Provide working plunker or pastebin etc. Check paths for component declarations.